PHP Laravel how to make mass update where one column value will update another column
I need to make simple thing but in Laravel standards.
UPDATE xxx_table SET col2 = col1

Thats all. Can not find proper method in DB facade.

The solution I found is
DB::update(['col2' => DB::raw('col1')]);

Its little weird to me.
